# Does being drunk have any downsides?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

As I drink more beverages, my drunkenness slowly increases. Does this have any effect on my abilities, negative or otherwise? I haven't noticed any impairment at all until I'm fall-down-drunk at which point I can't do anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no effect at all until you are falling down drunk.

You cannot drink anymore booze once you are drunk, on [St. Sneaky Pete's Day](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/St._Sneaky_Pete%27s_Day) there are [special](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/St._Sneaky_Pete%27s_Day_Stupor) drunken stupor adventures when you reach 26+ drunkenness, you can drink [green beer](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Green_beer) on that day to get 10 above your normal limit.

There is also a [Trophy](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Little_Chickadee) for going to the Trophy hut in Bordertown with 1000+ drunkenness.
The most efficient way to get this drunk is using the [Dungeon of Doom potion](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Dungeons_of_Doom_potion) that gives you drunkenness. The specific potion that has this effect is different for every player and between ascensions.